# Problemas al almacenar cadenas de caracteres de una clase en un array

Tags: c++, array, class

Mi programa consta de un menú que tiene:

1. Dar de alta.
2. Dar de baja.
3. Modificar.
4. Mostrar.
5. Salir.

Y la clase Persona con sus constructores y métodos.

La clase Persona es algo asi:

```
Class Persona{
private:
char* dni;
char* nombreCompleto;
int edad;

public:
Persona(char*, char*, int);
~Persona();
//Métodos accedentes y mutadores, y visualizar datos
};
```

y el constructor:

```
Persona::Persona(char* dni, char* nombreCompleto, int edad){
this->dni = dni;
this->nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
this->edad = edad;

}
```

Al pulsar 1 pedimos los datos:

```
char id[MAX_DNI], nC[MAX_NOMBRE];
int anios;
cout << "Introduzca el dni: ";
cin >> id;  
cin.ignore();
cout << "Introduzca su nombre completo: ";
cin.getline(nC, MAX_NOMBRE);
cout << "Introduzca la edad: ";
cin >> anios;
```

Luego creamos el objeto:

```
Persona persona1 = Persona(id, nC, anios);
```

Después de crear el objeto `persona1` llamamos a una función que almacena dicho objeto en el array. Hasta aquí todo bien. El problema viene cuando vuelvo a dar de alta a otra persona, los datos de la primera persona con caracteres se modifica.

### Ejemplo:

Damos de alta a la primera persona e imprimimos:

```
DNI: XXXXXXXXX
Nombre: Fulanito
Edad: 34
```

Volvemos a dar de alta a otra persona, pulsando 1:

```
DNI: YYYYYYYYY
Nombre: Pepe
Edad: 22
```

Y al imprimir todos los elementos del array imprime esto:

```
Persona 1:
DNI: YYYYYYYYY
Nombre: Pepe
Edad: 34

Persona 2: 
DNI: YYYYYYYYY
Nombre Pepe
Edad: 22
```

El DNI y el nombre de la primera persona se cambia por el de la segunda pero la edad se ha mantenido intacta.

Sabeis por qué ocurre esto? He intentado tambien destruir el objeto generado una vez introducido la información en el array pero tampoco funciona. Espero que se me haya entendido mas o menos y  muchas gracias!

Comment: No indicas el código del constructor ni cómo lo llamas exactamente así que es complicado decirte dónde se te está olvidando copiar la cadena

Comment: Seguramente estás reutilizando los arrays, todos los objetos persona apuntan a los mismos. No te pasa con la edad porque no se usa un puntero en ese caso.

Comment: Hola, he añadido el constructor y la clase. A qué te refieres con copiar la cadena? tengo que copiar por ejemplo la cadena id a otra cadena auxiliar y el crear el objeto con el id auxiliar o algo asi? Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Es probable que también sea por lo de usar punteros. Cómo podría arreglarlo? gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nota que `nC` es un puntero;

```
char id[MAX_DNI], nC[MAX_NOMBRE];
//                ^^ puntero
```

Y al crear el objeto le pasas al constructor dicho puntero:

```
Persona persona1 = Persona(id, nC, anios);
//                             ^^ AQUI
```

Y el constructor de `Persona` se limita a quedarse con una copia del puntero:

```
Persona::Persona(char* dni, char* nombreCompleto, int edad){
  this->dni = dni;
  this->nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto; // <<---
  this->edad = edad;

}
```

El problema es que no estás copiando el contenido del puntero sino únicamente el puntero en sí mismo. Es decir, todas las copias de `Persona` que hagas van a apuntar a la misma región de memoria, luego todas van a compartir el nombre (y lo mismo pasa con el DNI)

La solución básica pasa por no copiar punteros sino copiar los datos a los que se apunta:

```
Class Persona{
private:
  char dni[MAX_DNI];
  char nombreCompleto[MAX_NOMBRE];
};

Persona::Persona(char* dni, char* nombreCompleto, int edad){
  strcpy(this->dni,dni);
  strcpy(this->nombreCompleto,nombreCompleto);
  this->edad = edad;
}
```

Aunque siempre te va a quedar el código más limpio si usas `std::string` en vez de arrays de caracteres:

```
Class Persona{
private:
  std::string dni;
  std::string nombreCompleto;
};

Persona::Persona(std::string const& dni, std::string const& nombreCompleto, int edad){
  this->dni = dni;
  this->nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
  this->edad = edad;
}
```